# I cannot access to phpmyadmin after installing Jenkins

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy, jenkins

to install jenkins, as the instructions I followed says, I had to create this virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ci.company.com
    ServerAlias ci
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I cannot access anymore to http://localhost/phpmyadmin. It says:

> Status Code: 404
>
> Exception:  Stacktrace: (none)

What should I do?

Javi

Comment: The VirtualHost seems to be overkill. Can you revert back to your old directive, then try accessing http://localhost:8080/ ? I suspect that you can access the "Jenkins" from :8080 without the special apache directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently redirecting ANY requests to `localhost:80/` to `localhost:8080/$1`.  That means `localhost/phpmyadmin` will be redirected to `localhost:8080/pypmyadmin`, which is clearly not what you want.

My recommendation is to create Jenkins on a context (i.e., `/jenkins`), which will allow you to update the ProxyPass to be:

```
ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
```

Tomcat will, by default, mount this on a Jenkins context, so I'm assuming you're running this using the built-in init script that came with your deploy.  If this is the case, you'll need to add `--prefix=/jenkins` (or similar) to either `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, or append it to where you're manually running the server.

Subsequently, you could also ONLY pass in /jenkins, but you may run into issues with internal links; you can this via Apache like so (with no changes to Jenkins):

```
ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Thanks! but why do yo mention Tomcat? I "think" I'm not using it..

Comment: Jenkins can run under a Java Application Server such as Tomcat, if you so choose.  The new Jenkins packages include Winstone, which is also a JAS, but is bundled in with the package itself.  By default, Tomcat mounts `NAME.war` on `/NAME`, but I wanted to cover my bases. :)